# SQL Server primary Key violation in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Inserting those I am trying to insert records which don't have primary key violations.

I am trying to insert data using SQL Server stored procedure in vb.net. It is raising some primary key violations for some entries and as a result it doesn't insert any of the records including those which don't have primary key violations.
How can I have the records added which doesn't have key violations, and ignore the primary key violation

```
on error resume next
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim sqlcmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
sqlconn.ConnectionString = "Server=mymachine\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sqlcmd.CommandText = "mystoredprocedure"
sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn
sqlconn.Open()
sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: you should post the content of the stored procedure.

Comment: First, get rid of `on error resume next` We now have exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't VB.NET's issue, it's how you handle the data that you're trying to insert using your stored procedure.

You would have to check if the record exists first, if it doesn't, then insert.

Something like this:

```
if not exists (select * from table_you_are_inserting_to where key = @key_from_variable)
begin
    insert statement here
end
```

This will stop the primary key violation, and allows you to add an "else" to it, for an update statement instead (if you want the record to be updated)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are inserting multiple rows inside your stored procedure.

```
insert destination(pk, other_fields)
select pk, other_fields
from source
```

This operation executes a **single transaction**. It means **All Or Nothing** that is it **succeeds** when there is no violation or **fails** even in the case of a single violation. You can exclude wrong rows adding a easy check to the query.

```
insert destination(pk, other_fields)
select pk, other_fields
from source s
left join destination d on s.pk = d.pk
where d.pk is null
```

or use `merge` if you want to `update` existing matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping out. There were two issues, one was duplicate primary key and other being the data gathered also had primary key conflicts.
I chose a different primary key criteria to rule out those cases.